# \r\n \" printing out

Tags: php, adodb, mysql-real-escape-string

I have begun using ADOdb and parameterized queries (ex. $db->Execute("SELECT FROM users WHERE user_name=?;",array($get->id);)to prevent SQL injections. I have read this is suppose to protect you on the MySQL injection side of things, but obviously not XSS. While this may be the case, I'm still a bit skeptical about it.

Nevertheless, I always filter my environmental variables using shotgun approach towards safety at the beginning of my wrapper code (kernel.php). I notice the combination of using ADOdb and the following functions produces browser-visible carriage returns (\r\n \" \'), which is something I don't want (although I do want to store that information!). I also don't want to have to filter my output before display, since I already properly filter my input (aside from BBcode and that sort of thing). Below you will find the functions I'm referring to.

While in general I have isolated this problem to the mysql_real_escape_string portion of the sanitize function, do note that my server is running PHP 5.2+, and this issue does not exist when I use my own simplified db abstraction class. Also, the site is ran on mostly my own code and not built on the scaffold of some preexisting CMS). Thus, considering these factors, my only guess is there is some double-escaping going on. However, when I looked at adodb.inc.php file, I noticed $rs->FetchNextObj() doesn't utilize mysql_real_escape_string. It appears the only function that does this is qstr, which encapsulates the entire string. This leads me to worry that relying on parameterized queries may not be enough, but I don't know!

```
// Sanitize all possible user inputs

if(keyring_access("am")) // XSS and HTML stripping exemption for administrators editing HTML content
{
$_POST =    sanitize($_POST,false,false);
$_GET =     sanitize($_GET,false,false);
$_COOKIE =  sanitize($_COOKIE,false,false);
$_SESSION = sanitize($_SESSION,false,false);    
}
else
{   
$_POST =    sanitize($_POST);
$_GET =     sanitize($_GET);
$_COOKIE =  sanitize($_COOKIE);
$_SESSION = sanitize($_SESSION);
}

// Setup $form object shortcuts (merely convenience)

if($_POST)
{
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
        $form->$key = $value;
}
}

if($_GET)
{
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    $get->$key = $value;
}
}


function sanitize($val, $strip = true, $xss = true, $charset = 'UTF-8')
{
  if (is_array($val))
  {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($val as $key => $data)
    {
      $output[$key] = sanitize($data, $strip, $xss, $charset);
    }
    return $output;
  }
  else
  {
    if ($xss)
    {
      // code by nicolaspar
      $val = preg_replace('/([\x00-\x08][\x0b-\x0c][\x0e-\x20])/', '', $val);
      $search = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
      $search .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
      $search .= '1234567890!@#$%^&amp;*()';
      $search .= '~`";:?+/={}[]-_|\'\\';

      for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($search); $i++)
      {
        $val = preg_replace('/(&amp;#[x|X]0{0,8}'.dechex(ord($search[$i])).';?)/i', $search[$i], $val); // with a ;
        $val = preg_replace('/(&amp;#0{0,8}'.ord($search[$i]).';?)/', $search[$i], $val); // with a ;
      }

      $ra1 = Array('javascript', 'vbscript', 'expression', 'applet', 'meta', 'xml', 'blink', 'link', 'style', 'script', 'embed', 'object', 'iframe', 'frame', 'frameset', 'ilayer', 'layer', 'bgsound', 'title', 'base');
      $ra2 = Array('onabort', 'onactivate', 'onafterprint', 'onafterupdate', 'onbeforeactivate', 'onbeforecopy', 'onbeforecut', 'onbeforedeactivate', 'onbeforeeditfocus', 'onbeforepaste', 'onbeforeprint', 'onbeforeunload', 'onbeforeupdate', 'onblur', 'onbounce', 'oncellchange', 'onchange', 'onclick', 'oncontextmenu', 'oncontrolselect', 'oncopy', 'oncut', 'ondataavailable', 'ondatasetchanged', 'ondatasetcomplete', 'ondblclick', 'ondeactivate', 'ondrag', 'ondragend', 'ondragenter', 'ondragleave', 'ondragover', 'ondragstart', 'ondrop', 'onerror', 'onerrorupdate', 'onfilterchange', 'onfinish', 'onfocus', 'onfocusin', 'onfocusout', 'onhelp', 'onkeydown', 'onkeypress', 'onkeyup', 'onlayoutcomplete', 'onload', 'onlosecapture', 'onmousedown', 'onmouseenter', 'onmouseleave', 'onmousemove', 'onmouseout', 'onmouseover', 'onmouseup', 'onmousewheel', 'onmove', 'onmoveend', 'onmovestart', 'onpaste', 'onpropertychange', 'onreadystatechange', 'onreset', 'onresize', 'onresizeend', 'onresizestart', 'onrowenter', 'onrowexit', 'onrowsdelete', 'onrowsinserted', 'onscroll', 'onselect', 'onselectionchange', 'onselectstart', 'onstart', 'onstop', 'onsubmit', 'onunload');

      $ra = array_merge($ra1, $ra2);
      $found = true;

      while ($found == true)
      {
        $val_before = $val;
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ra); $i++)
        {
          $pattern = '/';
          for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($ra[$i]); $j++)
          {
            if ($j > 0)
            {
              $pattern .= '(';
              $pattern .= '(&amp;#[x|X]0{0,8}([9][a][b]);?)?';
              $pattern .= '|(&amp;#0{0,8}([9][10][13]);?)?';
              $pattern .= ')?';
            }
            $pattern .= $ra[$i][$j];
          }
          $pattern .= '/i';
          $replacement = substr($ra[$i], 0, 2).'<x>'.substr($ra[$i], 2);
          $val = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $val);
          if ($val_before == $val)
          {
            $found = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Strip HTML tags
    if ($strip)
    {
      $val = strip_tags($val);
      // Encode special chars
      $val = htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES, $charset);
    }

    // Cross your fingers that we don't get a MySQL injection with relying on ADOdb prepared statements alone… ? It works great otherwise by just returning $val... so it appears the code below is the culprit of the \r\n \" etc. escaping
    //return $val;

    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') or get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        return mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($val));
    }
    else
    {
        return mysql_real_escape_string($val);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help! If you need any further clarifications, please let me know.

**Update** the backslash is still showing up in front of " and ', and yes I removed the extra mysql_real_escape_string... now I can only think this might be get_quotes_gpc, or ADOdb adding them...

~elix

Comment: Why do you use `mysql_real_escape_string()` in conjunction with parameterized queries? This makes no sense at all. Parameterized queries render SQL escaping functions obsolete, don't use them together.

Comment: Oh, and try to avoid "Cross your fingers" comments in your code. ;)

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` will add backslashes before quotes and several other characters. By then putting that value into a parameterized query, where the string will get escaped again, you'll actually save the slashes as part of the string

Comment: I wondered if this resulted in an doubling-up of the escaping, but since I'm new to the parameterization concept, I wasn't sure (especially since I found no obvious signs of mysql_real_escape_string, addslashes, or anything of the sort in the code for the DB abstraction class). If I'm safe with parameterization alone, then I thank you all for your answers and affirmations!

Comment: When you use prepared statements, there is simply no concept of a SQL injection vulnerability to protect against. First, your DB class sends the query with placeholders, and the database saves an execution plan for it. Then, it separately sends the values you want to use in those placeholders and the query can be executed with those values. At no point is the query and its values concatenated into a single string, which is where SQL injection occurs by writing values that would change the query that string represents.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a side effect of qstr in ADOdb, even though I didn't reference that particular function of the class, but must be called elsewhere. The problem in my particular case was that magic quotes is enabled, so I set the default argument for the function to $magic_quotes=disabled. As for not needing any escaping with this, I found that ADOdb by itself DOES NOT utilize mysql_real_escape_string through the basic Execute() with binding alone! How I recognized this was due to the fact that the characters " ' threw errors (hence didn't render on my server where error_reporting is disabled). It appears the combination of the functions with fixing that small issue with ADOdb has me both well protected, and accepts most/all input the way I want it to: which in the case of the double quote prevented any quotes from being entered as content into the database, which meant at the very least no HTML

Nevertheless, I appreciate your suggestions, but also felt that my follow-up might help others.